# Flagging Entries with the Same Names?

Tags: python

I'm working with data where people have entered their names and some contact information. However, since they were unable to enter multiple entries for some of the fields, some people entered their names multiple times, resulting in 'duplicate' entries...

I'm trying to mark duplicate entries by the same user using a variable 'flag'.

For each row, what I want to happen is that if the name entry in the row is NOT the same as the name entry in the next row, the flag entry should increase by one.

How do I do this?

This is the code I currently have:

```
# FLAG 2

import csv

myjson = []

with(open("ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt", "rU")) as f:
     sheet = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
     sheet.fieldnames.append('flag')
     print sheet.fieldnames
     for row in sheet:
        myjson.append(row)

flag_counter = 0
myjson[0]['flag'] = flag_counter

for i in range(len(myjson)-1):
    if myjson[i]['name'] != myjson[i+1]['name']:
       myjson[i+1]['flag'] = flag_counter + 1
    else:
       myjson[i]['flag'] = flag_counter

for i in range(len(myjson)):
    print myjson[i]
```

This is example data:

```
name    phone   email   website    area   degree
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP 111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111    dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
Sam D. Man Ed.M.            
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    111-222-333     dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

And this is the output that results from operating on the example data:

```
['name', 'phone', 'email', 'website', 'flag']
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 0, 'name': 'Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.', 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.got.com', 'phone': '111-222-3333', 'flag': 1, 'name': 'Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP', 'email': 'cersei@got.com'}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 1, 'name': 'Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.', 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '000-000-1111', 'flag': 0, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': 'dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': None, 'phone': '', 'flag': 0, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': None}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '111-222-333', 'flag': None, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': '    dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 1, 'name': 'D G Bamf M.S.', 'email': ''}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 1, 'name': 'Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.', 'email': ''}
```

Note that the flags do not correspond to the desired pattern.

And here is an ideal output (notice the difference in flag entries):

```
['name', 'phone', 'email', 'website', 'flag']
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 0, 'name': 'Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.', 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.got.com', 'phone': '111-222-3333', 'flag': 1, 'name': 'Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP', 'email': 'cersei@got.com'}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 2, 'name': 'Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.', 'email': ''}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '000-000-1111', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': 'dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': None, 'phone': '', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': None}
{'website': 'www.daManWithThePlan.com', 'phone': '111-222-333', 'flag': 3, 'name': 'Sam D. Man Ed.M.', 'email': '    dman123@gmail.com'}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 4, 'name': 'D G Bamf M.S.', 'email': ''}
{'website': '', 'phone': '', 'flag': 5, 'name': 'Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.', 'email': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Ths loop workes for me (output as expected):

```
for i in range(len(myjson)-1):
    if myjson[i]['name'] != myjson[i+1]['name']:
        print "not same" ,myjson[i]['name'] ,' ', myjson[i+1]['name']
        flag_counter = flag_counter + 1
        myjson[i+1]['flag'] = flag_counter
    else:
        print 'equal', myjson[i]['name'] ,' ', myjson[i+1]['name']
        myjson[i]['flag'] = flag_counter
```

Note that I had to format the csv file by hand (tabs weren't tabs, but spaces). Make sure it is correct in your file. The names have to be exactly correct, no additional spaces allows

But I am not sure if this is the only bug, as there are many dangerous 'off-by-one' traps. If it still doesn't work, just update your output and code and we will see!

Comment: Why, flag_counter is always zero, so you assign 0+1 if it's a new name, otherwise 0. But you are right, that's most probably not the only bug...